# How get parametrs list for permission package in andoid

Tags: python, android, apk, adb

Please tell me how can I determine for an Android permission package a list of parameters in the system to which it gives access?

For example, if an application is given access to "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" then the application will actually have access to the "ad_aaid" parameter from the "global" category.

I have a list of packages for which I would like to know the list of parameters to which they provide access. Is it possible to somehow do this using the shell or other methods? Perhaps there is some documentation? Help me please.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but it seems to me that there is some way to get a list of parameters. For example, if an application initially does not have access to the "permission.ACCESS_WIFI" permission, but then I grant it, what list of parameters will the application be able to see?

Comment: In general, there will be no such parameters. Please bear in mind that you appear to be the only person who associates `com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID` and `ad_aaid`, based on Google and DuckDuckGo searches. You might consider linking to documentation that references this concept of categories, parameters, and permissions, even if just for `ad_aaid` and `com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID`.

Comment: There is no direct way to understand what a permission allows you to do, especially permissions from app that do not belong to the AOSP system. In the end you have to check which app(s) declare the permission and then fetch and decompile it (check AndroidManifest.xml and the source code) to find where it is referenced and what code you can execute if you have this permission.